# Removing auto <p> tag from Advanced Custom Fields in Wordpress BUT keeping the <br> tags

Tags: wordpress, filter, tags, textarea, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using this filter in Wordpress to remove the auto 'p' tags from ACF's text areas:

```
    function acf_wysiwyg_remove_wpautop() {

       remove_filter('acf_the_content', 'wpautop' );
       }

    add_action('acf/init', 'acf_wysiwyg_remove_wpautop');
```

It's working perfectly fine and removes the wrapping 'p' tag but it's also removing 'br' tags.

How can I keep the 'br' tags so I can still make line breaks in ACF text areas?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using the no line to break function:

```
function acf_wysiwyg_remove_wpautop() {
  // remove p tags //
  remove_filter('acf_the_content', 'wpautop' );
  // add line breaks before all newlines //
  add_filter( 'acf_the_content', 'nl2br' );
}

add_action('acf/init', 'acf_wysiwyg_remove_wpautop');
```

Tested on the latest WordPress with the latest ACF.